# Could you tell me why the code don't display facebook Like button

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I use the follwing code to display Facebook Like button, but I havn't got result, why?

The code is copied from FaceBook, it seems that the code lost http:

Thanks!

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Great Web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hicalc.com%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kYyQS/

Comment: I don't see the like button either........but I vaguely recall installing something that would kill them :p **edit:** i see it in IE, but not chrome or firefox

Comment: I tested it in Chrome on Win7 and Safari on Mac. Works fine for those.

Answer (score 1):

The omission of `http:` is intentional, valid and correct. It means that it will be on the same protocol that you are on.

- For `http://example.com`, it'll use `http://www.facebook.com`
- For `https://example.com`, it'll use `https://www.facebook.com`
- For `file:///example`, it'll use `file://www.facebook.com`

This last is what I imagine is tripping you up; it won't work on a local file.

Either (a) use a local web server so that it's `http://localhost` (a good idea as it removes the potential for various security restrictions and problems and makes the development environment more like the deployment environment) or (b) prepend `http:` while it's in development (try to remove it for deployment).